# BarChart3D: varying individual bar color

Tags: plotting, color, charts

I've been working with a chart like so:

```
data = {{0, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 2}} + .001;
BarChart3D[data, ChartLayout -> "Grid", Method -> {"Canvas" -> None}, 
 Axes -> None, FaceGrids -> None, BarSpacing -> 0, 
 ViewPoint -> 1.5 {3, -2.29, 3},
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Right now the entirety of each bar is rendered in some color based on its height. What I'd like is for the color of each bar to vary in the vertical direction, an effect similar to, for example

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Yellow, Purple}, #3] &)]
```

[image]

where the color of any point on the surface depends only on its z position. `ColorFunction` seems to offer a lot of control over the colors of objects; is there a way to specify a `ColorFunction` for each bar, or even all bars uniformly?

Comment: Search the docs for `"GradientScaleCube"`... perhaps

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ChartElementDataFunction["GradientScaleCube", "ColorScheme" -> cs]` as the option value for `ChartElementFunction` to apply a gradient scheme `cs` to all data.

```
data = {{0, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 2}};
options = {ChartLayout -> "Grid", Method -> {"Canvas" -> None}, 
   Axes -> None, FaceGrids -> None, BarSpacing -> 0, 
   ViewPoint -> 1.5 {3, -2.29, 3}, ImageSize -> 400};

Row[BarChart3D[data, options, 
    ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementDataFunction["GradientScaleCube", 
      "ColorScheme" -> #]] & /@ {"Rainbow", "SolarColors"}]
```

[image]

> *is there a way to specify a **ColorFunction** for each bar*

You can wrap each data set or each data point with the `ChartElementFunction` you wish to use. With `"GradientScaleCube"` as the `ChartElementFunction` you can inject your desired `ColorFunction` for a bar as the `"ColorScheme"` option:

```
data2 = {{0, 0, 1} -> ChartElementDataFunction["SquareWaveCube", 
     "AngularFrequency" -> 10, "RadialAmplitude" -> 0.26], 
   {3, 0, 0} -> ChartElementDataFunction["GradientScaleCube", 
     "ColorScheme" -> "Rainbow"],
   {1, 0, 2} -> ChartElementDataFunction["SegmentScaleCube", 
     "ColorScheme" -> "DarkRainbow"]};
data3 = {{0, 0, 1 -> ChartElementDataFunction["GradientScaleCube", 
      "ColorScheme" -> "Rainbow"]},
     {3 -> ChartElementDataFunction["GradientScaleCube", 
      "ColorScheme" -> "Rainbow"], 0, 0}, 
     {1, 0, 2 -> ChartElementDataFunction["SegmentScaleCube", 
      "ColorScheme" -> "DarkRainbow"]}};

Row[BarChart3D[#, options, 
    ChartElementFunction -> (If[#3 =!= {}, #3[[1]][#], 
        ChartElementDataFunction["DoubleProfileCube"][##]] &)] & /@ {data2, data3}]
```

[image]

**Update:** Using custom `ChartElementFunction`s to inject bar-specific color functions through metadata wrappers:

```
dt = Reverse[Range[3]] # & /@ Range[3];
grads = RandomChoice[ColorData["Gradients"][[11 ;; 16]], 9];
```

To use color gradients as metadata, use `pointi -> colorgradiendti` to assign `colorgradiendti`  to `pointi`:

```
dt1 = Partition[Rule @@@ Transpose[{Flatten@dt, grads}], 3];
```

and define the custom `ChartElementFunction` as:

```
cedF1 = ChartElementDataFunction["GradientScaleCube", 
     "ColorScheme" -> If[#3 =!= {}, #3[[1]], "Pastel"]][##] &;
```

To use `ChartElementFunction` as metadata, use `pointi -> ChartElementDataFunction["GradientScaleCube", 
      "ColorScheme" -> colorgradiendti]` to assign `colorgradiendti`  to `pointi`:

```
dt2 = Partition[Rule @@@ Transpose[{Flatten@dt, 
      ChartElementDataFunction["GradientScaleCube", "ColorScheme" -> #] & /@ grads}], 3];
```

and define the custom `ChartElementFunction` as:

```
cedF2 = #3[[1]][##] &;
```

Example:

```
Row[{BarChart3D[dt1, options, ChartElementFunction -> cedF1], 
  BarChart3D[dt2, options, ChartElementFunction -> cedF2]}]
```

[image]